# Формула для нахождения фигур Хладни

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, физика

1. Есть **фигуры Хладни**. В зависимости от частоты звука получаются фигуры из песка, соли и т.д.
   А.  [Фигуры Хладни ч.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMdsKtwmE44&feature=share&fbclid=IwAR3zkdisZj4n3W2LJtpctXL9fyCI2j0R6D-qaH-_fEy4wMIlz3MrDuqCOH0)
   Б.  [Фигуры Хладни ч.2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8z1AuLS-g8)
2. Как получить общую формулу для нахождения формы фигуры соли (песка) в зависимости от звука?

- Могёте помочь?

[image: рисунок ниже, "Фигуры Хладни"]

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/theory-behind-patterns-formed-on-chladni-plates

Comment: - Давайте сюда пишите, ребят, я знаком с правилами (если есть вопрос на англ. то напишите о нем на русском stackoverflow. см. Правила сайта), нужна формула, на javascript.Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Не, это не так работает. Ваш вопрос по сути разбивается на 2: 1) найти формулу. 2) записать ее на JavaScript. К этому сайту имеет отношение только вторая часть. А за первой Вас вполне справедливо отправили на physics.SE.

Comment: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WdKXRV

Comment: А какой параметр отвечает за частоту Звука, мой сердешный друг, @Stranger in the Q. Можно ли так получить такие же картинки как на картинке и видео?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts надо углубляться в в инфо по ссылке =) я особо не изучал, просто нашел, но скорее всего вот тут https://i.imgur.com/3uBhqzZ.png

Comment: Js будет долго справлятся с системой дифференциальных уравнений) Самый подходящий вариант это Matlab,Python,C++

Comment: @Stranger in the Q на каком языке написан Ваш (данный пример) как его перенести на javascript/html/css?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts это не мой пример, это glsl, язык шейдеров, выполняется на видеокарте, имеется js api - webgl, реализуется на нем

Comment: @Stranger in the Q А подойдет Three.js? Для данного кода? а то я не могу найти чистую либу одним файлом js? https://dmitrylavrik.ru/blog/javascript/threejs/osnovy-webgl-3d

Comment: Сразу скажу, код не мой! Это все проделки-подделки кружка `@Stranger in Q`:
[This link](https://codepen.io/arthur-alunts/project/editor/ANvKpB#0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Вот, пожалуйста, позаимствовал шейдер c ([shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WdKXRV)), у меня для этого есть своя мини библиотека:

```js
let rgba = new RGBA(`

  const float PI = 3.14159265;
  vec2 p = (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy - resolution.xy) / resolution.y;

  vec4 s1 = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  vec4 s2 = vec4(-4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 4.6);

  float a = mix(s1.x, s2.x, xy.x);
  float b = mix(s1.y, s2.y, xy.x);
  float n = mix(s1.z, s2.z, xy.y);
  float m = mix(s1.w, s2.w, xy.y);

  float amp = a * sin(PI*n*p.x) * sin(PI*m*p.y) + b * sin(PI*m*p.x) * sin(PI*n*p.y);
  float col = 1.0 - smoothstep(abs(amp), 0.0, 0.1);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(col), 1.0);

`, {uniforms: {xy: '2f'}});

addEventListener('mousemove', e => rgba.xy([e.x/innerWidth,e.y/innerHeight]))
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/strangerintheq/rgba/0.0.1/src/rgba.js"></script>
```

http://paulbourke.net/geometry/chladni/

https://thelig.ht/chladni/

Comment: Это не все! Мой дорогой друг!!! Есть еще кое-что: я недавно годиков так 10 назад занимался еще одним серьезным вопросом, когда писал дипломную. Тогда все и началось. Заяц ,мать его, он, мать его, убьет нас, мать его.Есть еще один интрестинг вопрос, который я хотел бы освятить, - про орбитали планет и мои любимые графики функций. (скоро напишу вопрос с ответом: дело было в Сочи) https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=sHsyuLs0D5o

Comment: могёте помочь никак ни могу сделать видео из этого без mouse event?

Comment: `const float PI` // `float a = `— А как называются эти штуки, и что нужно почитать, чтобы их понять?))

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Вы про что конкретно? я не особо понял

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Слово `float` - это вы сами через библиотеку ввели новый способ объявления переменной? Вот и не понятно, как)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME это не javascript, это glsl, язык шейдеров, там есть такой тип :)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME этот код, будет выполнен для каждого пикселя канвы, он возвращает цвет этого пикселя(gl_FragColor). На входе : gl_FragCoord - координаты пикселя, это встроенная в glsl переменная, resolution - размер канвы (эту переменную я сам устанавливаю в библиотеке)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME эта большая строка на входе не весь шейдер, а его тело, без некоторых переменных, полный код собирается конкатенацией перед компиляцией gpu программы. Загляните внутрь, в этой либе кода - 100 строк наберется, правда там ни строчки комментов :)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Ребят, как Вы меня не поняли, как убрать mouse ivents и сделать бесконечный цикл с меняющейся переменной, так чтобы получилась анимация а не event? Отредактируйте код или создайте еще один ответ!Заранее благодарен!

Comment: @ArthurAlunts просто убрать строчку addEventListener

Comment: @Stranger in the Q куда писать цикл, и какие переменные менять? )Вот что не догоняю!

Comment: @ArthurAlunts я дополню позже, сейчас не у компа

Comment: понимаю, понимаю. Вот да вот да!!! Вот вот брат, вот вот, вот не вот брат вот вот.

Comment: Вечером удобно в районе 18:00:29?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/bGdKrpr

Comment: Thanks!!! @Stranger in the Q

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME премного благодарен

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  Вау!!! После такого вообще задумываешься, а тем ли я вообще занимаюсь ))) Восхищаюсь Вашими работами!

Comment: Как вклинить сюда свои переменные типа var а не float?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts так как устанавливается значение координат мыши, через uniform

Comment: @Stranger in the Q поподробнее можно хотябы строчечку кода

Comment: @ArthurAlunts последняя строка в сниппете

Comment: @dmtr , https://codepen.io/arthur-alunts/project/editor/ANvKpB#0 как здесь добавить цикл для изменения в нем параметров

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWm6DTBhbcI    Как бы получить точно такой же опыт, кто знает?

Comment: Как теперь задать зависимоcть от частоты звука V и как теперь сделать итерацию параметров a, b, n, m в цикле for(){}?